# Как сделать так, чтобы recycler view прокручивался не отдельно, а вместе с элементом перед ним?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

У меня есть фрагмент с 3 элементами (toolbar, layout и recyclerview). Нужно, чтобы reсyclerview вместе с layout перед ним прокручивался под toolbar. Как это сделать?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.asus.testapp147.HomeFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <include layout="@layout/information_of_day" />

    <include layout="@layout/recycler_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Синей стрелкой показана требуемая прокрутка, а красной то, что есть сейчас (recycler view прокручивается под layout)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Гуглите: android recyclerview header. Туториалов полно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать [NestedScrollView](https://inducesmile.com/android-tips/android-recyclerview-inside-nestedscrollview-example/) примерно как-то так:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include layout="@layout/information_of_day"/>

<include layout="@layout/recycler_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Код неточный, подредактируйте под себя.